# python run redis error when crontab shell

Tags: python, redis, cron

i install redis-2.7.1 in my folder,and run my python code,it worked.

```
COMMON_MODEL_DIR="/data/aa/redis-2.7.1"
sys.path.append(COMMON_MODEL_DIR)
import redis
```

And when i set up crontab ,

```
*/10 1-23 * * * (cd /data3/aa/; python step.py 2 >> /data3/aa/2.log 2>&1)
```

But it won't worked
it will report

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "step.py", line 11, in ?
    import redis
  File "/data/aa/redis-2.7.1/redis/__init__.py", line 1, in ?
    from redis.client import Redis, StrictRedis
  File "/data/aa/redis-2.7.1/redis/client.py", line 157
    response = [nativestr(i) if i is not None else None for i in response]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How will i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the user account under which your cron job is running is using another (and quite old) Python version that doesn't support ternary expressions. Find out which Python *you* are using and pass the full path in your crontab.

Comment: can you please help me with my question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712982/storing-data-into-redis-through-cron-job